# Command Alias within a Batch Program

Tags: batch-file, alias

Hello,

I don't know if anybody can help me, because I've search a lot without success.

On my DOS Terminal (XP) I send successfully those commands :

```
doskey CS=call smile.bat $*                 
CS                  
or                 
CS arg1
```

It works PERFECTLY !
Then I insert these commands in a new batch file :

```
@echo off                  
doskey CS=call smile.bat $*     
CS arg1
```

Error returned : CS is an unknown command...

I do absolutely want to use aliases in my batch program, but I do not want to modify my Path nor my Reg, because it is just to use in the Batch itself. I want to find a solution, but I need any idea. Please if some one can help me with an example, it would be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT

You cannot run a [doskey](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/doskey.mspx?mfr=true) macro from a batch program.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to call a Batch file via another name, then just define another Batch file (with the second name) that call the first one. For example

CS.bat file may have this line:

```
@call smile.bat %*
```

then, in the first Batch file:

```
call CS
or
call CS arg1
```

If this is enough for you, then you may even create the alias Batch file inside the first Batch file this way:

```
echo @call smile.bat %%*> CS.bat
```

I hope it helps...